# Finding $n$ satisfying $\{1^n-0^n,2^n-1^n,\cdots,p^n-(p-1)^n\}\equiv \{0,1,\cdots,p-1\}\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

**Background** : About a month ago, a friend of mine taught me his findings about a few  polynomials which cover all the residue classes in mod $p$ where $p$ is a prime. Then, I began to consider the same problem for the other polynomials. Among some polynomials, $f(x)=(x+1)^n-x^n$ is the one that I can't grasp. So, here is my question.

> **Question** : For a given **odd prime** $p$, how can we find **every positive integer** $n$ satisfying the following condition?
>
> **Condition** : For $f(x)=(x+1)^n-x^n$, 
>   $$\{f(0),f(1),f(2),\cdots,f(p-1)\}\equiv \{0,1,2,\cdots,p-1\}\pmod p.$$
>
> **Remark** : We want that $f(x)$ covers all the residue classes $\pmod p$. The condition is **not** $f(x)\equiv x\pmod p$.

I conjecture that the answer is $n=(p-1)m+2\ \ (m=0,1,2,\cdots)$, but I'm facing difficulty in proving that. Maybe I'm missing something important... Can anyone help?

The followings are what I've got.

- $f(0)\equiv 1.$
- $f(p-1)\equiv -(-1)^n\Rightarrow \text{$n$ has to be even}\Rightarrow f(p-1)\equiv p-1$.
- For $n=(p-1)m+r$, $f(x)\equiv (x+1)^r-x^r$ because $a^{p-1}\equiv 1$ for $a$ which is coprime to $p$.
- $f\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)\equiv 0$.
- $f\left(\frac{p-1}{2}+a\right)+f\left(\frac{p-1}{2}-a\right)\equiv 0$ for any $a$.

**Added** : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199559/permutation-polynomials-mod-p-of-the-form-x1n-xn).

Comment: It seems like $f(0) \equiv 1 \text{ mod p}$ (rather than $0 \text{ mod p}$) for any $n$?

Comment: @John: $f(0)\equiv 1$ and $f(p-1)\equiv -(-1)^n$, so $n$ has to be even. Then, $f(p-1)\equiv p-1.$

Comment: Oh ... the condition is not that $f(m) \equiv m \text{ mod p}$, just that the sets are equivalent?  (I saw the parallel between the lhs and rhs and may have added an incorrect constraint.)

Comment: @John: The sets are equivalent. That's what I meant.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: @BillDubuque: A friend of mine taught me this question.

Comment: I cannot understand if we want that $(x+1)^n-x^n$ covers all the residue classes $\pmod{p}$ or the stronger constraint $(x+1)^n-x^n\equiv x\pmod{p}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: What I meant is the former.

Comment: I added the background of this question at the top because I think that adding it must be *better*.

Comment: There is a lot of literature on such polynomials, creatively called [permutation polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_polynomial).

Comment: @quid: Thank you for the nice information. I'm very glad to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer just to inform that the question has received an answer by Peter Mueller on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199559/permutation-polynomials-mod-p-of-the-form-x1n-xn).

The answer mentions that the expected answer is correct, and it is a theorem by Norman Johnson, see [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01223263).

Answer (score 0):

(This should really be a comment but its too long.)

I'm wondering if the information posted on the Wikipedia article on [permutation polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_polynomial) is correct. It lists that if $g(x)$ is a permutation polynomial, then so is $ag(x+b)+c$ and $ax^3+bx$ is a permutation polynomial iff $-b/a$ is a quadratic non residue. Using this, I can prove that $r = 4$ is valid for all primes $ \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. However, this only seems to work for the prime $3$...

The depressed for $(x+1)^4-x^4$ using the transformation $x \rightarrow x - \frac{1}2$ and dropping the constant is $4x^3+x$. Multiplying across by $4^{-1}$ transforms this into $x^3+(4)^{-1}x$. Now if 
$$ \left( \frac{-4^{-1}}p \right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}(2^{-1})^{p-1} \equiv -1 \pmod p $$
so $r = 4$ should work but checking the prime $7$, we can see that the polynomial does not work.

Answer (score 0):

To me problem seems more deeper and complicated than it looks. $n = (p-1)m + 2$ is one of the possible solutions if $m$ as such that $p \nmid n$.

If we want that $f(x)$ covers all residuals of $p$ we have to make sure that there are no two residual classes maps to the same class.

Say $k < p$ and $q < p$ maps to the same class. Then $f(k) - f(q) \equiv 0 (mod(p))$ Plugging it into function we get:
$$f(k)-f(q) \equiv (k-q)(P_{n-2}(k,q)) mod(p)$$ where $P_{n-2}$ is symmetrical polynomial of degree $n-2$.

For example, for $n = 2: P_0 = 2$; for $n = 3: P_1 = 3(k+q+1)$;

for $n = 4: P_2 = 4(k^2 + kq + q^2) + 6(k+q) + 4$ and so on.

Polynomials are symmetric but higher degrees residual equation require different math theory be involved.

Is it clear to see that we can find k,q so that $P_1 \equiv 0 (mod(p))$ It is not so easy to show for higher degrees when solution may not exists and be dependent on $p$.